# Mongodb scanning a lot of documents even after creating proper index

Tags: mongodb

I am facing a problem with mongodb query where even after creating a proper index for sorting the results documents scan is very high.
Below is the query

```
db.ratebus.find({
    $and: [{
        _id.trg: {
            $in: [54875973]
        }
    }, {
        rating: {
            $gte: 3
        }
    }]
}).sort({
    revType: -1,
    updated_at: -1
}).hint({
    _id.trg: 1,
    rating: -1,
    revType: -1,
    updated_at: -1
}).limit(10)
```

Below is the profiler output

```
2018-10-08T13:03:15.986+0530 I COMMAND  [conn1370938] command jdsocial.ratebus command: find {
    find: "ratebus",
    filter: {
        $and: [{
            _id.trg: {
                $in: [54875973]
            }
        }, {
            rating: {
                $gte: 3
            }
        }]
    },
    sort: {
        revType: -1,
        updated_at: -1
    },
    hint: {
        _id.trg: 1,
        rating: -1,
        revType: -1,
        updated_at: -1
    },
    limit: 10
}
planSummary: IXSCAN {
    _id.trg: 1.0, rating: -1.0, revType: -1.0, updated_at: -1.0
}
keysExamined: 37423 docsExamined: 37423 hasSortStage: 1 cursorExhausted: 1 keyUpdates: 0 writeConflicts: 0 numYields: 292 nreturned: 10 reslen: 4047 locks: {
    Global: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 586
        },
        acquireWaitCount: {
            r: 26
        },
        timeAcquiringMicros: {
            r: 179979
        }
    },
    Database: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 293
        }
    },
    Collection: {
        acquireCount: {
            r: 293
        }
    }
} protocol:op_query 692ms
```

It is clearly visible here that for a limit of 10 records it is scanning 37423 documents. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Sample records in db:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "src" : 2584095,
        "trg" : 54877444
    },
    "revid" : "0805639673",
    "rating" : 2,
    "age" : ISODate("2012-11-14T15:41:09Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-11-14T15:41:09Z"),
    "hasrev" : 0,
    "revType" : 0,
    "has_rev" : false,
    "rev" : ""
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "src" : 38266391,
        "trg" : 54878562
    },
    "revid" : "0805639674",
    "rating" : 4,
    "age" : ISODate("2012-11-14T15:41:14Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-11-14T15:41:14Z"),
    "hasrev" : 0,
    "revType" : 0,
    "has_rev" : false,
    "rev" : "",
    "comment_id" : NumberLong("1531272078171327")
}
```

Index Created:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id.trg" : 1,
        "rating" : -1,
        "revType" : -1,
        "updated_at" : -1
    },
    "name" : "_id.trg_1_rating_-1_revType_-1_updated_at_-1",
    "ns" : "jdsocial.ratebus"
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample of your docs, and index created?

Comment: added the sample records and indexes

Comment: create index  with combine `{revType: -1,updated_at: -1}`, might help you.

Comment: @IftekharDani its already there

Comment: Look like you have not create `index` for particular two fields `{revType: -1,updated_at: -1}`

Comment: @matthPen sample docs added along with the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting part should be in the [index prefix](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-index-prefix). The index you have

```
{
    "_id.trg" : 1,
    "rating" : -1,
    "revType" : -1,
    "updated_at" : -1
}
```

Does not support sort by

```
{
    revType: -1,
    updated_at: -1
}
```

The one that does should have indexed fields in the correct order:

```
{
    "revType" : -1,
    "updated_at" : -1,
    "_id.trg" : 1,
    "rating" : -1
}
```

Comment: Note that it does not have to be a prefix as long as all preceding columns are fixed. So the `_id.trg` can probably stay up front (but only if that `$in` is really just an equality match and does not take a longer list of options).

Answer (score 4):

To complete @Alex Blex's answer, i would say that sorting part should be in the index prefix BECAUSE you use $in in your query.

Let me explain : MongoDB is using index with the following strategy : 1)equality - 2)sort - 3)range. As you used $in in filter part of your query, this one is in the 'range' part of the strategy. So priority is given to sort stage, and it can not use properly your index as it's not matching the index prefix.

So two solutions for you : creating a new index as Alex said, or replacing `_id.trg: {$in: [54875973]}` with `_id.trg: {$eq: [54875973]}`. The only question to choose is "Do i really need a range of ids for this query?"